# Why does android WebView unable to download files in case of a POST Request?

Tags: android, http-post, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have implemented `DownloadListener` in `WebView`. I can download the files when the request is a `GET` Request. But the download never starts when the request is a `POST` Request.

```
webview.setDownloadListener(this);
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

DownloadListener (Which is never called)

```
@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Log.d("webview_down","onDownloadStart");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setMimeType(mimetype);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);

}
```

shouldOverrideUrlLoading(I can see the url being called but on downloading, it just creates a corrupt pdf file)

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d("webview_override",url);
            if(url.contains("/downloadstatement.htm")){
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "bs.pdf");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Also post a dump of the response of the server to your request.

Comment: Somewhere i found this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36909335

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug in Android then.

Comment: Try Android custom tabs, I was able to handle download requests there.